# Error C3867 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

My code was working fine until I reloaded the program a few hours later. Now I get these this error:

> error C3867: 'player::getxPos': function call missing argument list; use '&player::getxPos' to create a pointer to member
>
> error C3867: 'player::getyPos': function call missing argument list; use '&player::getyPos' to create a pointer to member

This is the code in question:

```
if (P->shoot())
{
    shotVector.push_back(shot());
    eS = shotVector.size();
    shotVector[eS-1].initShot(
        P->getxPos, // C3867
        P->getyPos // C3867
    );
}
```

I'm trying to call two functions from a class called player and these two functions look like this:

```
int player::getxPos(){
    return xPos;
};

int player::getyPos(){
    return yPos;
};
```

What's being done is that I'm trying to ask for the players position and then use that to decide where to shoot from.

Comment: "My code was working fine until..." - classic quote...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`shotVector[eS-1].initShot(P->getxPos, P->getyPos);` - you are trying to call the `getxPos()` and `getyPos()` members without `()`.

Use `getxPos()` and `getyPos()`.

Answer (score 8):

You forgot the parenthesis, which tell the compiler that you want a method call:

```
P->getxPos
```

vs

```
P->getxPos()
```

If you instead used `&P->getxPos`, that would give you a pointer to the member function itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
shotVector[eS-1].initShot(P->getxPos(), P->getyPos());
```